# Refresh window when username and password mismatch

Tags: node.js

I am building an application using node.js. I made a login form and it is working fine, but if the user enters the wrong username and password then he has to refresh the window and then type the right username and password in order to continue with the next screen.

What should I do to let the user enter after the login window without a refresh?

Explaining the above problem step-by-step:

1. User enters username and password (if both are correct).
2. User is logged in.

But:

1. User enters username and password (if either of them is wrong).
2. Refresh window.
3. User enters correct username and password.
4. User is logged in.

How can I avoid the "refresh window" step? I can explain more if this is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

I have edited the answer, you can do it like this.

```
socket.on('login_check', function(email, pwd) { 
    connection.query("SELECT id,user_type FROM user WHERE email = '"+email+"' AND password = '"+pwd+"'ORDER BY name ", 
    function (error, results, fields) { 
        if (error) { 
            console.log(error);  
        } 
        if (results[0]) { 
            // some code     
        } else { 
            response.writeHead(200, {
                'Location': '/login-path'
                // add other headers here...
                // you may also show the email in the text box
                // again by passing the variable email to the template
                // engine you are using or how ever you are doing it
            });
    response.end(); 
        } 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Can you help me further? 
My code is -

socket.on('login_check', function(email, pwd){
  
  connection.query("SELECT id,user_type FROM user WHERE email = '"+email+"' AND password = '"+pwd+"'ORDER BY name ", function (error, results, fields) {
   if (error) {
    console.log(error); 
   }
   if (results[0]) 
   {
    // some code    
   }
   else 
   {
    // how to use your code here ?
   }
  });
});

How to get response here??