# How to use response in node.js when connecting with database?

Tags: node.js, response

I have to use response.writehead to redirect to a different page. How can i do this in sql query.

Here is my code.

```
socket.on('login_check', function(email, pwd) { 
    connection.query("SELECT id,user_type FROM user WHERE email = '"+email+"' AND password = '"+pwd+"'ORDER BY name ", 
    function (error, results, fields) { 
        if (error) { 
            console.log(error);  
        } 
        if (results[0]) { 
            // some code     
        } else { 

           // Have to use response.writehead here. Please guide how to do this. If i use it here directly then it will give response is undefined error.

        } 
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you're using socket.io, not responding to a traditional HTTP request. Thus you have no "response" object to use. I suggest you use `socket.emit()` to send a message over the socket back to the client, and use client-side javascript to change `window.location` manually.

Comment: This will not server my purpose. Actuall my problem is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19567721/refresh-window-when-username-and-password-mismatch